# Outputfile generated on error

Tags: errors, luatex, output

If I run this example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Foo
\newpage
\barbaz
\end{document}
```

using

```
lualatex --halt-on-error minimal.tex
```

The log yields:

```
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

However, a file minimal.pdf **is** created (although I cannot open it). This seems to occur due to the first page being written. This confuses my buildsystem.

pdflatex does **not** create such a file. How do I switch lualatex to the expected behavior? Is this a bug?

Comment: I suspect you can't. You might want to raise that as a possible bug on the luatex list.

Comment: well I suppose you could try to add some file cleanup into the `show_error_hook` lua callback

Comment: You haven't said what system you are on -- but are you sure the pdf file is not open in some software (e.g. Acrobat reader) thereby locking the file. Try rebooting.

Comment: I have found a possible bug in a source (pdfgen.w), and reported
to the LuaTeX developer.

Comment: The patch will be applied and the bug will be fixed
in the next release.

Comment: @AubreyBlumsohn did you try it on your system? It seems to be a generic behaviour as noted by Akira Kakuto.

Comment: @Akira Kakuto: Thank you. Would you make an answer out of this (preferably linking to the bug report), so I can close this question as answered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a bug in pdfgen.w, that the condition to remove
a broken pdf in the case of a fatal error was wrong.
Thus the broken pdf was not removed.
As an answer, we have to wait for the next release, or
have to build a new binary ourselves by using sources which
will be updated soon.